# Programmatically: Export Einstein Analytics Dashboard as Image or PDF

Tags: apex, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein, einstein-analytics-dashboards

is it possible to export an Analytics Dashboard programmatically? Programmatically could be APEX or any API like the Analytics API.

The three Options i tried are

- via "Print Preview": Did not found a way to trigger this function with less effort.
- Share Option: The Image generation does not always, sometimes SF says that it is not possible to generate. Also it seems to be more a Thumbnail Image rather than a high resolution Image.
- *PageReference(quoteURL).getContentAsPDF()* (APEX) which is unable to work because of the lack of CSS 3 support.